# Node require mongo error - 'require is not defined'

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules, node-webkit

I'm having a problem with mongo and node. I have a file called db.js where I put the `require('mongodb')` and if I import it to my index.html, I got the error:

> require is not defined

But if I go to the db.js file and use 'node db', it works. I've tried import, require, src but still nothing works. Someone could help me?

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        import 'js/db.js';
```

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb');
```

Comment: the browser doesn't know about `imports` nor `require`, you will need a transpiler, but even with that I don't think you will be able to connect to mongo from the browser :S

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason that you need to configure mongodb on the front end? Unless you have a **really** good reason, I would **strongly** recommend against that. You basically throw any notion of security right out the window by doing that.

Now that we've got that cleared up, I think what you really are asking, is how you can let users make requests to mongodb from the front end. For that, you should use `fetch` or an HTTP request/response library like `Axios` in your front end javascript. Use either of these to send requests to your node backend and then you can interact with mongodb by passing along the user-submitted data from there.

Let me know if that helps you at all or if you need more help.

Answer (score 0):

You should require mongodb statement on server side code not on the browser side.Browser don't understand the require/import statement.

You can try using module like browserify to see such functionality if it works.

http://browserify.org/